SOQL query count of contacts with no cases
I am looking to do a SOQL query to extend this query to include the count of the number of cases related to the contact:
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT ContactId FROM Case)

The above query returns all the contacts with no cases. This is good.
I want to return all contacts and the count of the cases they have related.
Something like:

etc.
Thank you in advance!

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You want to use a SOQL aggregate query, probably with a GROUP BY ROLLUP.

The only option is normal aggregate query:
SELECT COUNT(ID), ContactID 
FROM Case 
GROUP BY ContactID

But, this query will not show any Contact that have zero Cases, because we are querying on the Case and we cannot query record if there is no any.
If you have to include the caseless Contacts, you must use Apex or custom rollup field on the Contact object. There is app for that called DLRS

Note that Group by works only if there are less than 2000 matches, in this case 2000 unique contacts. If there are more, then it is going to be an error. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm

Thank you for this. I can compare the output with the list of all contacts and filter out those that aren't in the aggregate list.
Cheers!

The below query returns all contacts and their related cases.
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Cases) FROM Contact
To get the count of related cases along with all contacts, you would need to handle this in Apex. SOQL does not allow counting directly in subqueries.
List<Contact> listOfContacts = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Cases) FROM Contact];

for (Contact con : listOfContacts) {
    Integer casesRelatedToContact = con.Cases.size();
    System.debug('Contact Name: ' + con.Name + ', Number of cases related to contact: ' + casesRelatedToContact);
}


Won't it throw Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop error when there are more than 200 Cases?
